# Add differente classes from buttons from other component Angular 10

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add classes to a div from three buttons of other component.
When I am in the same it works correctly, the problem is when the div is in one component and the buttons in another.

- navbar component:

```
<nav class="c-navbar" aria-label="Navegacion principal">
    <ul class="c-navbar__list">
        <li class="c-navbar__item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/one']" routerLinkActive="is-active" (click)="theme = 't-blue'" class="c-navbar__link">one</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c-navbar__item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/two']" routerLinkActive="is-active" (click)="theme = 't-red'" class="c-navbar__link">two</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c-navbar__item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/three']" routerLinkActive="is-active" (click)="theme = 't-green'" class="c-navbar__link">three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

- app component:

```
    <div [ngClass]="theme" class="o-wrapper"> 
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

- navbar component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../../../scss/components/_c-navbar.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
theme: string

  constructor() { 
 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are trying to access and update the theme variable inside the navbar component, which will not update the main app component theme variable . You should use Eventemittors to emit some output to app component and then update theme variable inside app component.

You can refer to below link for more details to use Eventemitters

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: I've used the EventEmitter but still can't get the button click event to change the class in the other component to work. I can't find what the problem is:

Answer (score 0):

I've used the EventEmitter but still can't get the button click event to change the class in the other component to work. I can't find what the problem is:

- navbar component html:

  ```
  <nav class="c-navbar" aria-label="Navegacion principal">
      <ul class="c-navbar__list">
          <li class="c-navbar__item">
              <a [routerLink]="['/section-one']" routerLinkActive="is-active" (click)="theme = 't-blue'" class="c-navbar__link">one</a>
          </li>
          <li class="c-navbar__item">
              <a [routerLink]="['/section-two']" routerLinkActive="is-active" (click)="theme = 't-red'" class="c-navbar__link">two</a>
          </li>
          <li class="c-navbar__item">
              <a [routerLink]="['/section-three']" routerLinkActive="is-active" (click)="theme = 't-green'" class="c-navbar__link">three</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  ```
- navbar component ts:

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
selector: 'app-navbar',
templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./../../../scss/components/_c-navbar.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

theme:any;

@Output() heroeSeleccionado: EventEmitter<any>;


constructor() {

  this.heroeSeleccionado = new EventEmitter();
  
}

ngOnInit(): void {
 
}

verHeroe(){
  this.heroeSeleccionado.emit(this.theme);
}

}
```

- app component html:

  ```
  <div (heroeSeleccionado)="verHeroe($event)" class="o-wrapper"> 
      <app-navbar></app-navbar>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  ```
- app component ts:

  ```
  import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';


  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./../scss/components/_c-app.scss']
  })

  export class AppComponent {

    @Input() verHeroe: any;


  }
  ```